# Set a focus in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a below situation:

An activity, with a Fragment-A.

On user input, a new Fragment (lets call it Fragment-B)is added, by using below code:

```
ft.add(R.id.content_frame, fragmentB);
```

Now, when I press back, the fragment-B is destroyed as expected.

As fragment-B was **added(and not replaced)** there is no callback to `onResume()` of Fragment A.

I need to set focus of fragment-A as soon as fragment-B is destroyed.

I use below code to set the Focus:

```
getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
getView().requestFocus();
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For those developers who are struggling to get the "callback" in Fragment`( when fragments are added and NOT Replaced )`, can try below method:

Use `addOnBackStackChangedListener` which adds a new listener for changes to the fragment back stack.

I added this `addOnBackStackChangedListener` in `onCreate()` method of my Fragment-A, as below:

```
getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new OnBackStackChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (getView()!=null){
                    getView().setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                    getView().requestFocus();       
                }               
            }
        });
```

Now As soon as Fragment-B is destroyed, `onBackStackChanged` is called and I was able to set the focus.

Of course, you can write whatever code you want to execute inside `onBackStackChanged` when Fragment is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

Create an interface:

```
public interface DestructionListener {
    void onDestroyed();
}
```

Now in your FragmentB class put an implementation of Subject:

```
private DestructionListener listener;

public void setDestructionListener(DestructionListener listener) {
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

Still in the same fragment, apply such change:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    ...
    if(listener != null)
        listener.onDestroyed();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Now you have Listener pattern implemented - you can listen for an event which occurs when FragmentB is being destroyed. In your activity, just put:

```
fragmentB.setDestructionListener(new DestructionListener() {
    void onDestroyed() {
        // Request focus here
    }
});
```

and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply hide the fragment(in which you dont want focus) and show the one u want focus since you are adding fragments and not replacing.