# How to switch existing fragments when the dialog is closed?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bottomnavigationview

The main screen of the app is for `bottom navigation`.

And there are 3 menus, all of which are `fragments`.

Pressing the button on one of the fragments opens the `dialog fragment` window.

And when the dialog is closed, the old fragment should be switched to another new fragment.

I use `show()` and `hide()` instead of `replace()`.

***MainAcitivity.java***

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    BottomNavigationView bottomNav;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);

        bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
                Fragment curFrag = fm.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
                String tag = String.valueOf(item.getItemId());
                int id = item.getItemId();

                if(curFrag != null) {
                    transaction.hide(curFrag);
                }

                Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(tag);
                if(fragment == null) {
                    if(id == R.id.list)
                        fragment = new WorkoutListFragment();
                    transaction.add(R.id.content_layout, fragment);
                }
                else {
                    transaction.show(fragment);
                }

                transaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
                transaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
                transaction.commitNow();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // Switch to another fragment when the dialog is closed
    public void onFragmentChanged() {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        String tag = "ABC";

        Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.getPrimaryNavigationFragment();
        if (currentFragment != null) {
            fragmentTransaction.hide(currentFragment);
        }

        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(tag);
        if (fragment == null) {
            fragment = new WriteRoutineFragment();
            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
        } else {
            fragmentTransaction.show(fragment);
        }

        fragmentTransaction.setPrimaryNavigationFragment(fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.setReorderingAllowed(true);
        fragmentTransaction.commitNow();
    }
}
```

***DialogFragment.java***

```
    Button startBtn;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_body_part_dialog, null);
        startBtn = view.findViewById(R.id.check);

        startBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) { 
                MainActivity activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();
                activity.onFragmentChanged(); // change fragment
                dismiss();

            }
        });

        return view;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
        dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return dialog;
    }
}
```

***WriteRoutineFragment.java***

```
public class WriteRoutineFragment extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_write_routine, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }
}
```

***ERROR***

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0a0082 (com.example.writeweight:id/container) for fragment WriteRoutineFragment{f3a9b6 (137e8e27-12af-4e5a-9397-2cbdc80ed980) id=0x7f0a0082 ABC}
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:875)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1696)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:293)
        at com.example.writeweight.activity.MainActivity.onFragmentChanged(MainActivity.java:78)
        at com.example.writeweight.fragment.BodyPartDialogFragment$2.onClick(BodyPartDialogFragment.java:89)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
        at android.widget.TextView.performClick(TextView.java:16221)
        at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:992)
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
        at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30236)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8506)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 23516 SIG: 9
```

---

***ADDED***

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.MainActivity">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/bottom_nav"/>

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

***fragment_write_routine.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragment.WriteRoutineFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You're using `R.id.content_layout` in your `onNavigationItemSelected` method, but `R.id.container` in your `onFragmentChanged` method. The error message says that `R.id.container` doesn't exist in your activity's layout. Can you include that layout?

Comment: This is another alternative to your problem: What if you check [when a fragment lost and regains focus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29746092/set-a-focus-in-fragment)? So after you close your dialog you check which fragment should focus

Comment: @ianhanniballake i added xml code, I'm not very good at what exactly your answer means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, tag);
```

What you're saying is that you want the FragmentManager to find the `R.id.container` in your layout and add your fragment to that container. As you're using `getSupportFragmentManager()`, you're using the Activity's FragmentManager and hence, `R.id.container` needs to be in your activity's layout. However, `R.id.container` isn't in your activity's layout, which is why you're getting an exception.

Instead, you should be using the container that **is** in your Activity's layout - `R.id.content_layout`:

```
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_layout, fragment, tag);
```

Comment: Oh, you mean the `FragmentManager` is using `R.id.content_layout` in `onNavigationItemSelected()`, but when using the `FragmentManager of an activity` in `onFragmentChanged()`, an exception occurred using `R.id.container` that is not in the activity's layout?

Comment: That's what I said, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping me